# Should i save my id both in redis key and value?

Tags: redis

Imagine i save highschool classes and students.

The key is composed like so: `${student.className}:${student.studentId}`

I need to get the list of classes with the students in each class

```js
{
    science: {
        students: {
            123321: {
                // user data
            },
            234432: {
                // user data
            }
        }
    } 
    //etc
}
```

When debating with colleagues, there was a dispute as to whether we should "extract" the class name and student id from the keys, or simply save them as part of the object.